# Как посмотреть все символы шрифта и их кодировку?

Tags: css, шрифты

Есть шрифт `FontAwesome`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подключить его к стилям, и свойству `content` псевдоэлемента задать `\f092`, то отобразится иконка GitHub'a. Но это я подсмотрел на каком-то сайте через консоль.

А как посмотреть все символы и их кодировку, которые присутствуют в шрифте?

П.С: Вопрос относиться к любому шрифту. `FontAwesome` взят в качестве примера.

Comment: вы под windows ?

Comment: @Максим Ленский, ага)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите шрифт в windows штатным образом и откройте его в штатном же приложении "Таблица символов".

Comment: Я так и сделал. Но такой способ меня не сильно привлекает. Грузить все подряд  в копьютер... фее))

Comment: Вы и без того грузите "все подряд в компьютер". Можно шрифт не устанавливать в систему, а просто посмотреть, но покажет не все символы.

Answer (score 1):

[Посмотрите здесь.](https://fontawesome.ru/all-icons/)

Или можно подгрузить сюда любой иконочный шрифт https://icomoon.io/app/#/select.

Answer (score 1):

После подключения этого шрифта в браузере через f12 ->source будут файлы шрифтов при нажатии на них покажутся все символы которые в нем есть 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще есть сайт http://fonts4web.ru/ubuntu.html там можно скачивать шрифты, там же есть примеры можно вписать любой текст в нужном шрифте

Comment: Проиллюстрируйте ответ скринами. Где там смотреть код символа?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше поздно, чем никогда.
Есть великолепный набор программ - FontMassive от Алексея Коноплева (aka KLesha28)
Скриншот просмотра глифов в шрифте не устанавливая его в систему:
[image: FontMassive Packages]

Сайт автора программы - https://fontmassive.com/
Сборка инсталяции полного пакета программ - https://github.com/nice-studio/FontMassivePackInstaller